# Error: Non-static variable inout cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am working on a program for my CS class that involves methods and variables. I know it's a problem with the scope, or at least I think, but not sure how to solve. I can't use objects. The code isn't complete yet, because I'm currently just focused on this one problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MethodBankingSystem {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static double Deposit(double userDeposit, double userBalance) {
         System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
            userDeposit = input.nextDouble(); //Create variable userDeposit for amount entered
            userBalance = userBalance + userDeposit; //Replace value for userBalance
            System.out.printf("New balance after deposit is: $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance );
            return userBalance;
        }
public static double Withdraw(double userWithdraw, double userBalance) {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
            userWithdraw = input.nextDouble(); //Create variable userWithdraw for amount entered
            if (userWithdraw > userBalance) { //Create if/else statement to make sure enough funds are available
                System.out.printf("Funds are not available for this withdraw \n\n");
            }
            else {
                userBalance = userBalance - userWithdraw; //Replace value for userBalance
                System.out.printf("New balance after withdraw is: $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance );
            }
            return userBalance;
        }
public static void CurrentBalance(double userBalance) {
        System.out.printf("Current balance is $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance ); 
    }







public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 double userBalance = 100.00;
 double userDeposit;
 double userWithdraw;
 double userInput;
 String cardNumber;

    String menu = "Welcome to Mustang Bank\nPlease choose from the options below:\n1 - Make a Deposit\n" +
            "2 - Make a Withdraw\n3 - Check your Current Balance\n9 - Exit the Program\nEnter Option:\n";





    do {
        System.out.print(menu);
        userInput = input.nextDouble();

        switch (userInput) {
        case '1':
            Deposit(userDeposit, userBalance);
            break;
        case '2':
            Withdraw(userWithdraw, userBalance);
            break;
        case '3':
            CurrentBalance(userBalance);
            break;
        case '4':
            CurrentBalance(userBalance);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("This option is not acceptable.");
        }

        } while (userInput !=9);
    }





    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is this:

`static` means that there is only one instance of that field per class (not instance). The field is essentially shared between all instances; modifying it in one instance will affect it in all instances. You can reference static fields within instances but you cannot statically reference instance members.

Either make `input` static (not really recommended):

`static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Or make an instance of `MethodBankingSystem` and remove the static modifiers from your methods (this is what I think you are trying to do):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MethodBankingSystem {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public double Deposit(double userDeposit, double userBalance) {
             System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
                userDeposit = input.nextDouble(); //Create variable userDeposit for amount entered
                userBalance = userBalance + userDeposit; //Replace value for userBalance
                System.out.printf("New balance after deposit is: $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance );
                return userBalance;
    }

    public double Withdraw(double userWithdraw, double userBalance) {
            System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
                userWithdraw = input.nextDouble(); //Create variable userWithdraw for amount entered
                if (userWithdraw > userBalance) { //Create if/else statement to make sure enough funds are available
                    System.out.printf("Funds are not available for this withdraw \n\n");
                }
                else {
                    userBalance = userBalance - userWithdraw; //Replace value for userBalance
                    System.out.printf("New balance after withdraw is: $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance );
                }
                return userBalance;
    }
    public void CurrentBalance(double userBalance) {
        System.out.printf("Current balance is $" + "%.2f \n\n",userBalance ); 
    }







    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MethodBankingSystem();
    }

    MethodBankingSystem () {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     double userBalance = 100.00;
     double userDeposit;
     double userWithdraw;
     double userInput;
     String cardNumber;

    String menu = "Welcome to Mustang Bank\nPlease choose from the options below:\n1 - Make a Deposit\n" +
            "2 - Make a Withdraw\n3 - Check your Current Balance\n9 - Exit the Program\nEnter Option:\n";





    do {
        System.out.print(menu);
        userInput = input.nextDouble();

        switch (userInput) {
        case '1':
            Deposit(userDeposit, userBalance);
            break;
        case '2':
            Withdraw(userWithdraw, userBalance);
            break;
        case '3':
            CurrentBalance(userBalance);
            break;
        case '4':
            CurrentBalance(userBalance);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("This option is not acceptable.");
        }

        } while (userInput !=9);
    }



    }
```

**I FIXED YOUR CODE GET IT BEFORE THE QUESTION GETS DELETED**

Because I'm a nice guy I fixed your code. There were all sorts of issues, please read up on them. You create an instance of input twice, you are switching on a double you are calling Deposit(userDeposit, userBalance); without initialisinguserDeposit, you declare cardNumber but never instantiate or even try to use it anywhere, you have issues with static scoping.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodBankingSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MethodBankingSystem();
    }

    Scanner input;
    double userBalance = 100.00;

    MethodBankingSystem() {

        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;

        String menu = "Welcome to Mustang Bank\nPlease choose from the options below:\n" + "1 - Make a Deposit\n"
                + "2 - Make a Withdraw\n" + "3 - Check your Current Balance\n"
                + "9 - Exit the Program\nEnter Option:\n";

        do {
            System.out.print(menu);
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            switch (userInput) {
                case 1:
                    Deposit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Withdraw();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    CurrentBalance();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("This option is not acceptable.");
            }

        } while (userInput != 9);

        input.close();
    }

    public double Deposit() {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
        double userDeposit = input.nextDouble(); // Create variable userDeposit for amount entered
        userBalance = userBalance + userDeposit; // Replace value for userBalance
        System.out.printf("New balance after deposit is: $" + "%.2f \n\n", userBalance);
        return userBalance;
    }

    public double Withdraw() {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
        double userWithdraw = input.nextDouble(); // Create variable userWithdraw for amount entered
        if (userWithdraw > userBalance) { // Create if/else statement to make sure enough funds are available
            System.out.printf("Funds are not available for this withdraw \n\n");
        } else {
            userBalance = userBalance - userWithdraw; // Replace value for userBalance
            System.out.printf("New balance after withdraw is: $" + "%.2f \n\n", userBalance);
        }
        return userBalance;
    }

    public void CurrentBalance() {
        System.out.printf("Current balance is $" + "%.2f \n\n", userBalance);
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked, but it created a new bug I think. Error now says "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: I didn't fix all your code I left that as an exercise for you (I didn't even look at it other than adjusting those few static references), but I'm willing to help. What line is the error on?

Comment: Thanks! Line 55 and Line 58

Comment: Also I was sort of implying that you don't use `static` in this case as it is not appropriate, `static` should only appear once in your code, here: `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: You'd have to post your code, edit your question and post it below your original bits

Comment: So I just looked at your code and you have quite a few problems in it... You create an instance of `input` twice, you are switching on a `double` you are calling `Deposit(userDeposit, userBalance);` without initialising`userDeposit`, you declare `cardNumber` but never instantiate or even try to use it anywhere, you have issues with static scoping.

Comment: @cococunt check out the update in my reply. I imagine your question will be deleted soon so be quick!